# SearchView onQueryTextSubmit runs twice while I pressed once

Tags: multithreading, searchview

I am writing a search function to access a library website.And when the query string is submitted,program launches a new thread to parse infos on the web.
   it runs normally on AVD but  my HTC DesireHD displayed the search results repeatedly,(if the real results are 1. 2. 3. it would appears to be 1. 2. 3. 1. 2. 3.).
   I set breakpoints at the onQueryTextSubmit method ,found that codes in method onQueryTextSubmit() were executed twice.
and here is my code:

```
sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            list.clear();
            String str = null;
            try {//encoding Chinese character
                str = new String(query
                        .trim().getBytes(), "ISO-8859-1");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            SearchPost sp = new SearchPost(SEARCH_URL + str);
            new Thread(sp).start(); 
            return false;
        }
    });

protected class SearchPost implements Runnable{
    public String url = "";
    SearchPost(String urls){
        url = urls;
    }
    public SearchPost() {
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Message message = handler.obtainMessage();
        message.what = DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE;
        try{
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                handler.sendMessage(message);
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            message.what = DOWNLOAD_FAIL;
            handler.sendMessage(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why have you given the return value of the method as false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finding out why clicking the button once causes onQueryTextSubmit to fire twice is an issue on its own that you might not be able to solve as it is controlled by the OS that might be buggy. The real question is about properly handling the case where the button is clicked twice or more in quick succession which would probably have the same effect. I suggest to have the list.clear() moved in the same place where you populate the list.

Comment: Moving list.clear() as you suggests does work.but the connecting thread is still executed twice,left program a potential bug...thanks anyway~

Comment: On the platform on which your program works OK, what would happen if you click twice in a quick sequence?

Comment: Repeated display as my HTC does I guess ,and I think I have figured out why that happened---pressing "search" produces ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP,both trigger submit method on some devices.it turns out a bug that we cannot control,you're right.

Comment: As a workaround, you could add a flag that prevents more than one thread to be started at the same time.

Answer (score 31):

Clearing focus on the **SearchView** helped me.

**sv.clearFocus();**

Note: *This hides the keyboard as well.*

Answer (score 3):

As the problem is  that user presses search key on keyboard produces two key-event ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP,and some device would react to both these two messages.

I solved in a simple way, as I do not like the setIconified(), because, then searched text is erased, I just let one search per second, so have done this:

```
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {

    long actualSearchTime = (Calendar.getInstance()).getTimeInMillis();
    // Only one search every second to avoid key-down & key-up          
    if (actualSearchTime > lastSearchTime + 1000)
    {
        lastSearchTime=actualSearchTime;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I keep looking for the cause and solution of this matter,and find something.
the reason why that happen:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24599

the action that user presses search key on keyboard produces two key-event ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP,and some device would react to both these two message(supposed to react to ACTION_UP only) , it turns out to be a bug of SDK or Device themselves that can't be controled by us developers.

To solve this , I add "sv.setIconified()" to empty the querytext in order to make ACTION_UP invalid.

Comment: This, that is the real problem. I would rather solve it by not re-running an on-going or done query though (requires a way to identify the query - with the query string for example - and maybe a way to re-run the same query but after some time). Messy in any case.

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue because I used _searchView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);, so by removing this line the onQueryTextSubmit function called once

Answer (score 0):

I solved mine by  placing a flag to know when the action occurred.

```
 var isEntered = false

 override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
      if (!isEntered) {
          // perform the action you want to undertake here
        isEntered = true
      }
     return true
 }

   override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        isEntered = false
    }
```